# See if JButton was clicked in MouseEvent

Tags: java

[Paint type thing failure][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApYbY.png
[Paint type thing failure][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQHvw.png
I have these 3 buttons that are supposed to be different paint colours but it only takes the first one like the first one..... so green even when I click on the paint colour button but it is showing that its going through all of them but isn't changing the paint colour when i press them it just makes a little circle at the top of the screen instead howw would i do it so i can check if the button was pressed in the mouse event thingy so it knows that the button was pressed and changes the colour to what its supposed to be.... the buttons are all JButtons if that matters.. like right now the paint colours just checks if like the paint colour id exists not the button but like howw do i make it so checks if the button was pressed and make it so it like actually changes the paint colour.

Comment: See `ActionEvent.getSource()`

Comment: You can use a ColorButton (https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/ex/ColorButton.java)

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i put 2 images of the stuff inside it already https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApYbY.png  and https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQHvw.png the other stuff was just this stuff https://ibb.co/bPt8w9h

Comment: The code in your `mouseDragged()` method doesn't work. The condition on the first if statement is `ID.Paintgreen == paintygreen(this)` and the `paintygreen(this)` method returns `ID.paintgreen` and therefore the condition of the first if statement is always true.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense now that I think about it yah i could see why it wasn't going to the others then how would I change it so it would only be true if the green paint button was pressed rather then it always being true like if it was like a light switch or something so pressing one button turns the others off and so on so like if green is pressed the others are turned off then if I click purple it like flicks that one on and the others off?

Comment: One possibility: you use a field that contains a reference to the last selected color (this could even be of type `Color`). Your `actionPerformed()` handler updates that field (`lastSelectedColor = Color.GREEN);` or `lastSelectedColor = new Color(198, 23, 255);`). The `mouseDragged()` handler uses that color (`g.setColor(lastSelectedColor);`.

Comment: O.o ooooh cool it is actually working now thankss....!!!! :D

Comment: is there a way to make a image change after a few seconds then a few seconds later I tried to put a gif as a cursor but for some reason it makes it freeze if u click on it or if its set to preview when you hover over it the thing wont work at all like it just wont open and when i tried to put an animated cursor it doesn't read it so yah is it possible to like set an image on a timer to change then change back and make it keep doing that so it could like look like its animated?